# Simplest way of validating RequestBody json syntax errors on Controller in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

I have the following controller which handles several business logic exceptions. However, if client sends a request body with syntax error for e.g in json format, it throws an exception.

What annotations and how would you use to return friendly message back to the client if the RequestBody or Json format has issues ?

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> createMovie(@Valid @RequestBody Movie movie) {
    try {

        Movie newMovie = movieService.create(movie);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(newMovie.toString());
    } catch (  MediaValidationException | IllegalArgumentException e ) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(movie.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: I would add a `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)` and this would guarantee that only a valid Json can be received in your request body.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this:

I was getting HttpMessageNotReadableException so I made an exception handler method for that and it worked. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Invalid request body format");
}
```